# SSRS Data Driven Subscription empty destination folder

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS Data Driven Subscription, the reports are save to a folder, I use the Overwrite Write Mode, however there are old reports that aren't generated anymore that lingers on the folder, I would like to clear the destination folder before running my subscription is this possible?

If No what is my alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a scheduled batch file to clear old files older than X days - tried and trusted!

Something along the lines of:
http://www.lynch.ie/wordpress/index.php/how-to-schedule-a-task-to-delete-files-from-a-specific-folder/